# ASP.NET MVC RenderPartial Error Code CS0029

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc

Not sure what went wrong, but the error is "CS0029: Cannot implicitly convert type 'void' to 'object'" at the Html.Partial.The other post said it should be enclosed with curved brackets, but its still not working (with and without). I have tried with Html.RenderPartial and Html.Partial, both don't work.

```
<div class="row" id="dtRecipe" style="margin-top:15px">
    @*@{ 
        Html.RenderPartial("_ListRecipe", new List<Eatery.Model.Models.Recipe>(), ViewData);
    }*@
    @Html.Partial("_ListRecipe", new List<Eatery.Model.Models.Recipe>(), ViewData);
</div>
```

The code for _ListRecipe is

```
public async Task<ActionResult> _ListRecipe()
{
    int DishID = Convert.ToInt32(ViewData["DishID"]);
    List<Recipe> recipes = (await recipeService.Get(DishID)).ToList();
    return PartialView(recipes);
}
```

The recipeService is okay as it is used in another file.

Comment: could you share your `_ListRecipe` ,  I think  the partial view is cause the error

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `;` at the end, it should be (without razor code block syntax):

```
 @Html.Partial("_ListRecipe", new List<Eatery.Model.Models.Recipe>(), ViewData)
```

If you want to properly use `Html.RenderPartial`, this is the right type of syntax (See code below), which means you need to create a razor syntax code block and there is a `;` at the end:

```
@{
   Html.RenderPartial("_ListRecipe", new List<Eatery.Model.Models.Recipe>(), ViewData);
}
```